# Visual Studio Deploy to SQL Data Warehouse Incorrect Syntax Near 'ANSI_NULLS'

Tags: visual-studio, azure, sql-data-warehouse

I would like to deploy a Database Project in Visual Studio 2017 to Azure SQL Data Warehouse. Unfortunately each attempt fails with the following error message

> Failed to import target model [database name]. Detailed message Parse Error at line: 1, column: 5: Incorrect Syntax near 'ANSI_NULLS'.

Connecting via SQL Server Object Explorer and simple querying are working fine. Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I just tried to deploy the Project to an Azure SQL Database, which finished successfully, so it seems to be due to the SQL Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but Database Projects are not currently supported for Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

You might like to vote for it here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/13313247-database-project-from-visual-studio-to-support-azu

Comment: The idea has apparently been started on 4th October 2018.